# modx - display php errors

Tags: php, modx

I am trying to upgrade modx from version 2.0 to 2.2 but I all I see is an empty homepage and no error messages.

I receive nothing in the error logs, is there a way to turn on php errors (I already have display_errors set, and error_reporting to E_ALL)

Thanks

Comment: make sure to clear your MODX cache (core/cache/ directory) and see if that helps.

Comment: Worked perfectly - if you answer the question I will accept your answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure to clear your MODX cache (core/cache/ directory) and see if that helps.